# ValueError when db settings altered in settings.py Django documentation

Tags: python, django, oracle

Hi iam following [Django documenatation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/),I have installed **Django 1.8** and **python 2.7.12**,I want to connect to oracle 11g database,For this I have altered **settings.py** file in mysite folder like this for DATABASE information

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE' : 'django.db.backends.oracle',
        'NAME' : 'XE',
        'USER' : 'chandan',
        'PASSWORD' : 'root',
        'HOST' : 'localhost',     }
}
```

Iam getting below error when i run `python manage.py runserver` and

```
python manage.py migrate

       from .utils import InsertIdVar, Oracle_datetime, convert_unicode
  File "C:\PYTHON27\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\oracle\utils.py", line 10, in <module>
    (int(Database.version.split('.', 2)[1]) >= 1 or
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '0rc1'
```

Do i have to alter my **DATABASE part in settings.py** or what needs to be done?

Comment: Which version are using of oracle dB. Try specifying the port also

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, check your connection for ORACLE.

Add port information.

Be sure to install cx_Oracle driver-lastest version.

Answer (score 0):

You are running an incompatible oracle version, Django's oracle drivers tries to cast the version string as an int, which obviously fails as the oracle version string contains `0rc1`.

You might want to install a newer release of Django, 1.8 is EOL and does not receive any security patches. And if you are starting a new project, do yourself a favor and choose Python 3 :-)

Comment: Hi Odi,Is there any compatible oracle version for django 1.8?The database settings i made above,is that correct?

Comment: I can see in Django documentaion that it supports oracle 11.1 and higher.I have my oracle 11.2 db ready,what am i missing here?